# Porque mi div se va hacia abajo?

Tags: html, css, div

el caso es que estoy haciendo un proyecto (soy principiante) y estoy estructurando una pagina web de html. El caso es que dentro de un div he creado otros dos, pero el segundo de estos en vez de quedarse dentro del principal, se va hacía abajo. Os dejo el  para que lo veáis.

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="nav">
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="main">
        <div id="section">
            <div id="article">
            
            </div>
            
            <div id="aside">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="footer">
        
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

En especifico, se va el div "aside".
Si alguien pudiera ayudarme sería de gran ayuda porfavor, dejo el css también, ya que creo que es problema de este. Cualquier ayuda sirve muchas gracias.

```
    #section{
    margin:9px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-bottom:9px;
    width:auto;
    height:850px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#article{
    margin:9px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-bottom:9px;
    width:1100px;
    height:830px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#aside{
    margin:9px;
    width:800px;
    height:830px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si le pones a #section una altura fija y entre los 2 que están dentro la superan el segundo siempre saldrá. Prueba quitando la altura a #section y este se adaptará a lo que hay en su interior.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muchísimas jaja, soy nuevo en esto y aún no lo tengo muy dominado, todo está solucionado, mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes **varias opciones** para solucionar esto, yo te brindo 3 enfocadas en el cambio del **height** en el *#section* de tu archivo **.CSS**. Elige la que prefieras:

- Aumentar los px a más (de tal forma que quepan ambos divs):

```css
#section{
    margin:9px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-bottom:9px;
    width:auto;
    height:1700px; // -> Línea modificada (aumentada en px)
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#article{
    margin:9px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-bottom:9px;
    width:1100px;
    height:830px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#aside{
    margin:9px;
    width:800px;
    height:830px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="nav">
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="main">
        <div id="section">
            <div id="article">
            
            </div>
            
            <div id="aside">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="footer">
        
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

*(Opción no recomendada del todo, ya que si quieres que te quede ajustado tendrás que ir ajustando tú los px conforme vayas viendo).*

- Eliminarlo, de tal forma que no haya problema a la hora de la inserción del segundo div:

```css
#section{
        margin:9px;
        margin-top:9px;
        margin-bottom:9px;
        width:auto;
        // -> Línea modificada (borrada)
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: dotted;
    }

    #article{
        margin:9px;
        margin-top:9px;
        margin-bottom:9px;
        width:1100px;
        height:830px;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: dotted;
    }

    #aside{
        margin:9px;
        width:800px;
        height:830px;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: dotted;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
            
            </div>
            
            <div id="nav">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="main">
            <div id="section">
                <div id="article">
                
                </div>
                
                <div id="aside">
                
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="footer">
            
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
```

*(Esta opción junto con la última son las más recomendables para que quede perfectamente ajustado).*

- Comentar la línea, de tal forma que esa línea no la lee el compilador, no pierdes el número que tenías puesto por si lo necesitas para más tarde, y te sirve igual que como si lo hubieras quitado:

```css
  #section{
    margin:9px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-bottom:9px;
    width:auto;
    //height:850px; // -> Línea modificada (comentada)
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#article{
    margin:9px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-bottom:9px;
    width:1100px;
    height:830px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#aside{
    margin:9px;
    width:800px;
    height:830px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="nav">
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="main">
        <div id="section">
            <div id="article">
            
            </div>
            
            <div id="aside">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="footer">
        
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

*(Opción recomendada)*

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, he probado las tres maneras para ir entendiendo y las tres han ido bien, me he quedado con la tercera, ya está solucionado y ahora lo entiendo jeje. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Perfecto, de nada!!!

Answer (score 0):

Le estás dando una altura específica al #section(850px) y la altura sumada de #article y #aside es mayor(830px + 830px = 1660px), son elementos en bloque así que uno se va para abajo y por tanto desborda por debajo de su elemento padre. La opción más obvia sería comentar el height de #section (visualizar en pantalla completa para correcta interpretación):

```css
#section{
    margin:9px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-bottom:9px;
    width:auto;
    /* height:850px; */
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#article{
    margin:9px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-bottom:9px;
    width:1100px;
    height:830px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#aside{
    margin:9px;
    width:800px;
    height:830px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="nav">
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="main">
        <div id="section">
            <div id="article">
            
            </div>
            
            <div id="aside">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="footer">
        
        </div>
    </div>
```

La otra opción sería no modificar el height del elemento padre, sino el display y width de los elementos hijos de forma que quepan en el height del elemento padre (visualizar en pantalla completa para correcta interpretación):

```css
#section{
    margin:9px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-bottom:9px;
    width:auto;
    height:850px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#article{
    margin:9px;
    margin-top:9px;
    margin-bottom:9px;
    width:1100px;
    height:830px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#aside{
    margin:9px;
    width:800px;
    height:830px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#article, #aside{
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
 <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="nav">
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="main">
        <div id="section">
            <div id="article">
            
            </div>
            
            <div id="aside">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="footer">
        
        </div>
    </div>
```